# Ajuda - DIV circular com imagem de fundo responsiva

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Caros, boa tarde!

Estou precisando de ajuda para criar uma div com imagem de fundo.

Eu fiz esse código:

```css
.this-image{
    //border: 2px solid #AD235E;
    border-radius: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 190px; 
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
section{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <div class='this-image' alt="título um" style="background-image: url(img/test.jpg);"></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

porém quando eu testo em resoluções grandes a imagem não escala, deixando um espaço banco ao lado.

Gostaria que a imagem aumentasse um pouco, até o ponto de interrupção em que eu deixaria outra div similar lado-a-lado.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Como assim? A div circular tem dimensões fixas. Vai ter sempre o mesmo tamanho em qualquer resolução.

Comment: pois é, era nisso que eu queria ajuda, em saber se tem como aumentar ou diminuir, não precisa ser necessariamente com essa estrutura de css

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, o que você precisa existe no CSS3 e chama-se: `background-size`.

> A propriedade background-size do CSS especifica o tamanho das imagens de fundo. O tamanho da imagem pode ser totalmente ou apenas parcialmente comprimido com o objetivo de preservar sua proporção.

na sua `class .this-image` considere utilizar:

```
background: url(img/test.jpg) no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Outra coisa, não utilize o style inline, igual você fez aqui: `<div class='this-image' alt="título um" style="background-image: url(img/test.jpg);"></div>` isto não é uma boa prática.

Logo, retire este style e acrescente na sua class acima. Conforme eu exemplifiquei.

Abraço, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: obrigado! É necessário definir heigth e width?, pois no primeiro teste a imagem desapareceu rsrs

Comment: Outra dúvida, eu terei que carregar em média 10 divs com imagens similares, o que é mais interessante, usar tag img ou o style? Fiquei preocupado em usar tag img devido as requisições.